# How to save array to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I would like to save an array of view controllers in NSUserDefaults, but I am not sure how:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tabBarController.viewControllers forKey:@"tabOrder"];
```

When I read the above line, my tabBarController.viewControllers is blank.

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389593/saving-uitabbarcontroller-view-controllers-to-nsuserdefaults-doesnt-work

Please don't ask the same question in two different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view controllers in this array are not serializable, and thus won't be saved to `NSUserDefaults`.

From the [NSUserDefaults reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:):

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects. See “What is a Property List?” in Property List Programming Guide.

You should re-initialize your view controllers on the next load. You can however serialize their data to `NSUserDefaults` to some custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

ere you can Save Object With NSUserDefault..

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.flipsideView.zoznamFunkcii] forKey:@"NSMutableArray"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

and you make coder and decoder method

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
  if (self = [super init]) {
      self.toolResult = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"obj1"];
      self.toolNotes = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"obj2"];

  }
  return self;
  }
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
  [encoder encodeObject:self.toolResult forKey:@"obj1"];
  [encoder encodeObject:self.toolNotes forKey:@"obj2"];

}

your Data Save Into NsuserDefault When you Get Data From NsUserDefault then you Use like
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"NSMutableArray"]];